# Can you get a union of string literals from a readonly string tuple?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create an interface that describes a structure like this...

```
const myObject: MyInterface = {
  keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'], //Arbitrary length and string literals, array is readonly
  props: {
    a: null //OK
    b: null //OK
    c: null //OK
    d: null //Invalid, 'd' is not in keys tuple
  }
}
```

From what I can gather there shouldn't be an issue for TypeScript to infer this at compile time, given that the keys array cannot change and only has string literals. Here is what I've tried at the moment:

```
interface MyInterface {
  readonly keys: readonly string[];
  readonly props: Record<this['keys'][number],any>;
}
```

This only manages to infer that the keys must be strings, not that they must match the given literals. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm actually after?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use `type` here, instead of `interface`.

```js
type Result<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = {
    keys: T
} & {
        [P in T[number]]: any // you can put here any type
    };

type Test = Result<['a', 'b', 'c']>

const test: Test = {
    keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 3 // error
}
```

Comment: While this is a decent workaround to get the desired restriction in place, it requires that the keys array is duplicated as a tuple type parameter. This is precisely what I'm trying to avoid, I'd much rather have that parameter be inferred from the array, which should be technically feasible since the array is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define your constant types.
There might better options, but below 2 suggestions. You can assign `MyInterface`  or `MyInterface2` to your object and in both cases any prop key that does not match a,b or c wont be allowed.

```
const a = 'a';
const b = 'b';
const c = 'c';

type myConsts = {
  a: any,
  b: any,
  c: any
}

type anyOfMyConsts = typeof a | typeof b | typeof c;

interface MyInterface {
  readonly keys: readonly  anyOfMyConsts[];
  readonly props: Record<this['keys'][number],any>;
}

interface MyInterface2 {
  readonly keys: readonly  anyOfMyConsts[];
  readonly props: myConsts;
}

const myObject: MyInterface2 = {
    keys:['b', 'b', 'c'],
    props: {
        a:1,
        b:2,
        c:3
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5HFBuAUKSsBGSq+mO40MwRKwpWUAngA4CmMAtgwMLlQREBvLDHgAueGAYAaYTHzi4kmSOALJWAL5Z6zNooYB5AGYBZbr37JGrEEfgwAPjGstbcx891vg2bVgCWYFAsAE5GcMBsZgCSQaHhkTBCIiEscAAm4AA2DDAA1iwMEOKpGdm5Eoam5ngQANoAutgpaZlgOTBMISBMxTAASiygIekAPFAAFv71KAVFKA11YACu7PihDVL6AHzYWgFxYRFRDLHBR5EATEmypW0dc3135SL6xmY8tY3NMM-tuV0en1OJ9oBA9tpcBROAZ8AArIZQcQxQ4JFjXZDJET5QrFOooEhSYgoIk0BbKbGA3riLHY7FwUQARgpdJE8kuLNZqgAzLIRFp9lggA)